# Cancel requests on subview when navigating from parent viewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm currently working on an app with a viewcontroller that has a number of subviews. Some of these subviews make requests (as in urlRequests) for data to display within the subview.

Now if someone navigates away from the main viewController I want to cancel any unfinished requests in the subviews. Is it enough to cancel these requests in the "dealloc" method of a subview as obviously they don't have a viewwilldisappear method. I'm using ARC and iOS 6 for what it's worth. Otherwise should I create my own cancel method in the subviews, and then loop through them in the viewWillDisappear of the main viewcontroller to call this method?

Or is the approach of the subviews making the request wrong to begin with?

The closest thing I could find to my question was [view will disappear is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279705/view-will-disappear-is-not-firing) which seems to suggest dealloc should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, your views (the subviews) should only take care of displaying a content.

The requests should be done by a dataManager singleton for example or from the view controller (You could use an NSOperationQueue).

I would then create a cancel method that stops the current request and remove the next ones from the queue.

Putting the cancel code in the dealloc or the viewDidDisappear is up to you. If you think you're view will only disappear for a short amount of time then put it in the dealloc.

You could also listen to the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification to cancel the requests too.